# Как быстрее и правильнее вывести изображения?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Имеется папка img, в которой +1000 изображений, количество изображений всегда разное... Как мне их быстро и правильно вывести в  блоке с классом: imgs?

Comment: [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.directoryiterator.php), но это никак не повлияет на скорость рендеринга изображений в браузере.

Comment: Предположу, что использовать http2 и послать изображения в push-режиме (но после других важных файлов - типа скриптов и стилей). Понятия не имею, как это сделать на php. Хотя в любом случае надо пробовать и замерять.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `glob()` для этого

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: 99 из 920 выводит.....(

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = '/где_картинки?';

$objects = $recursive ? new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
) : new DirectoryIterator($dir);

$imgs = array_filter($objects, function(SplFileInfo $sfi){
  return $sfi->isFile(); // фильтруем тут ненужные файлы
});
$imgs = array_map(function(SplFileInfo $sfi) {
  $url = '/'.$sfi->getBasename(); // Тут ваше урлообразование
  return "<img src=\"$url\" />";
});

echo implode("\n", $imgs);
```

Comment: не работает ваш вариант